# Не могу понять в чем ошибся. С# WPF/

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: Вот код:]

Ошибка CS0162. Не могу понять где ошибся. Код на C# WPF

Comment: и код текстом помещайте, пожалуйста, в след.раз

Comment: это не ошибка, а предупреждение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы сами чисто логически рассудите. Вот у вас есть `V`. Вы пишите условие `>= V` (от `V` включительно до плюс бесконечности) и `<= V` (от минус бесконечности до `V` включительно) ..... А другого и не может быть. Поэтому ниже условий просто не пойдёт код

Comment: Точно я забыл переменную исправить... Спасибо что обратили внимание на мою ошибку

Comment: Немного не согласен. Хоть ваши рассуждения и железобетонно верны, но именно компилятор отметил недостижимым кодом инкремент `i++`, так как в теле цикла присутствует конструкция `return`, из-за которой цикл не выполнит больше одной итерации. Аналогично со вторым циклом.

Comment: мне нужна как раз одна итерация, поэтому я использовал return

Comment: @n1ghtlights тогда вам не нужен цикл.

Comment: @aepot ну уж извините, я только учусь

Comment: @n1ghtlights цикл нужен для повторения выполнения комманд. Если комманды повторять не надо - в цикле пропадает.